# Request Approvals by E-mail and process it Python + Django

Tags: python, django, email

Maybe I am not asking the right question in the search area, but I can't find an answer for this. I am pretty sure that many people have this use case, but as a beginner in Django + Python, I need to ask it.

I have user that fills up a form and the data is stored in the database. Basically this form asks for an access to a Database and after the form is submitted I want my program to send an email to the user's manager and to the DBA to APPROVE or DENY it. Very simple, right?

My idea is that in this e-mail I send two URL's, one for approving and one for denying the request. When the URL the is clicked I send a response to the server with an update in the manager_approval field.

Has anyone implemented this solution, or could point me to something that could help me?

I am doing everything using Django + Python.

Regards,
Marcos Freccia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this technique used in email verification. This is where you should look into.

Let's say you have **model**, named request, which has field like username to identify the person who requested access, database name, well, everything. But it will also have two "password-like" fields which will be used to determine if request was declined or not.

```
class Request(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey ...
    databasename = 
    date = 
    ...
    access_granted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    deny_token = models.CharField()
    allow_token = models.CharField()
```

The point is to generate those tokens on saving request in the **View**:

```
if request.method == POST:
    form = RequestForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        data['user'] = form.cleaned_data['user'])
        data['databasename'] = form.cleaned_data['databasename'])
        ...
        data['access_token'] = GENERATE_USING_HASH_FUNCTION()
        data['deny_token'] = GENERATE_USING_HASH_FUNCTION()

        form.save(data)
```

Then you can use module `EmailMultiAlternatives` to send html email like so:

```
subject, from_email, to = 'Request', 'admin@example.com', form.cleaned_data['manager_email']
html_content = render_to_string(HTML_TEMPLATE, CONTEXT) # Just as any regular templates
text_content = strip_tags(html_content)

msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to], reply_to=["admin@example.com"])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

And inside that template you construct reverse url:

```
{% url 'app:grant_access' allow_token=token %} # "token" you get from context
{% url 'app:deny_access' deny_token=token %} # will become example.com/deny_access/7ea3c95, where 7ea3c95 is token
```

Then add lines to urls.py of your app like that:

```
url(r'^allow_access/(?P<allow_token>[0-9]+)$', CheckAcessView.as_view(), name="app:grant_access"),
url(r'^deny_access/(?P<deny_token>[0-9]+)$', CheckAcessView.as_view(), name="app:deny_access"),]
```

Then create `CheckAcessView` view. Where you access request stored in your database and check if, for example, parameter of url "allow_token" is equal stored allow_token. If so, change request status to allowed.